# How to make a dropdown list filter on the header of telrik RadGrid column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-interface, markdown

I'm using Telerik with asp.net and webforms

I have the following code:

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel" runat="server" >
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
            MasterTableView-EditMode="Batch" OnBatchEditCommand="RadGrid1_BatchEditCommand" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="100" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both"  >
            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
            <mastertableview datakeynames="RulCode, Year" datasourceid="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom"  
                CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" EditMode="Batch" AllowNaturalSort="true" >
                <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" OpenEditingEvent="Click" />
                <ColumnGroups >
                    ...
                </ColumnGroups>
                <Columns>  
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn ColumnGroupName="Class"  DataField="Group" HeaderText="Group" UniqueName="Group" ReadOnly="true"
                        HeaderStyle-Width="180px" FilterControlWidth="70%"  AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains"/>
```

is there anyway to have `<telerik:GridBoundColumn .../>` filtered with a dropdown menu rather than a text field? I'll also need the data in the dropdown to be unique

Comment: You can put the dropdown in the `filtertemplate` of the column. I think there might be examples in Telerik demo site.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's for asp.net, I can't find filtertemplate in the doc for asp.net

Comment: `FilterTemplate` is a one of the radgrid column templates such as ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate, ... . Please check [Filter Template Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/filtering/filter-templates/defaultcs.aspx) . May be there is an old version issue.

Comment: oh yes, that's it thanks, I couldn't find it when searching for some reason, you can add it as an answer I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: You can also enable the filterHeaderContextMenu which includes canned dropdown list filtering support. You'll need to bind into an event to populate it but it works well.